# Access another user's directory as admin on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

I've created a new account on Windows 10 with admin access. I want to access a folder on C: that is the user directory for another user.

I click the folder in exploer and it says ""click to permanently get access to this folder". I do this and it enters some kind of demented search mode with a green progress bar in the file path and just hangs. It makes me very sad. How to stop this infuriating problem please? I don't want to have to keep switching accounts to be able to accees folders.

[image]

Comment: The result you see when accessing a secured Users folder from another Windows User Account is entirely normal. Does the green bar finish? You did not say. Is User Account Control ON or OFF? It should be ON.  You cannot (overall) stop the process you see, but if you are the main Windows admin (not a company computer), you should be able to get access.

Comment: Well I gave up after 5 mins. Why do I need to wait to get access?

Comment: Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run (1) dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  and then (2) SFC /SCANNOW  .  Allow all to finish, restart and test.

Comment: It depends on how large the folder is and how slow the PC is. Windows' NTFS permission system will not let you access folders that you don't have permission to access, however, as an administrator you can change the permissions on a folder. This is what is happening while the green bar is moving in Explorer. In my experience, this can take anywhere from 30 seconds to several minutes depending on the number of files in the folder and the disk access speed. No need to run dism.